# Cast a user control in another control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am working on an ASP .NET project using .NET framework 3.5. I am trying to cast a user control inside another user control thus i am using the following code.

in the test.ascx file:

```
<%@ Reference Control="test2.ascx" %>
```

and in the test.ascx.cs file:

```
    private ASP.test2_ascx testing;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 testing = (ASP.treestructure_ascx)LoadControl("test2.ascx");
                testing.aload();
```

The problem is that the word "ASP" is underlined saying that "Error17 The type or namespace name 'ASP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
"

Comment: Why you place the ASP. in front ? Do you have try to use only the `test2_asxc` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the straight away. Make `treestructure_ascx` and `test2_ascx` files inherit from an interface having a signature aload that implements both the controls.

```
public interface ICustomLoader
{
    public void aload();
}
```

For both the controls:

```
public class treestructure_ascx : UserControl, ICustomLoader
{
    public void aload()
    {
        //your loading codes goes here
    }
}
```

and for test2_ascx

```
public class test2_ascx : UserControl, ICustomLoader
{
    public void aload()
    {
        //your loading codes goes here
    }
}
```

So, you will be able to cast the control and using `LoadControl`, you will able to access your `aload()`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var testing = (ICustomLoader)LoadControl("test2.ascx");
    testing.aload();
}
```

NOTE: I guess you don't need `ASP` namespace.